Calculating coordinates grid intervals - minutes and seconds in QGIS
I would like to define the coordinates for the grid to 15' intervals. This means ideally 15°15', 15°30'
Here are the coordinates for the grid/area of interest:
15°48'0"E
16°0'0"E
16°12'0"E
21°48'58"S
22°1'5"S
Defined as per the parameters below;

The map user finds these coordinates weird and would like to have them as 15˚30’ to 17˚E, and 21˚30’ to 22˚15 and I do not know how to define this.
The issue that I have is perhaps similar to this and thus maybe a duplicate to this question, Equal geographic coordinate grid intervals
However the hints provided does not help me discover the answer.

15' are 15/60 of a degree or 0.25 degrees: set to this value instead of 0.2 degrees

This seems to have worked for the East coordinates but not for the South, I set the Y interval to 0.3666666667 and only one line is crossing my map? I would like to have two ideally?

Why did you set it to 0.366 which is every 21.96' (0.366*60) if you want every 15' ? You need to set it to 0.25 as well.

Thank you alot.
